# Detect if Expo app opened from notification

Tags: expo

I need to detect if my Expo / React Native mobile app has been opened by a user clicking on a notification. I'm using `expo-notifications` to schedule my notifications. The Expo documentation doesn't seem to give any guidance on what I'm trying to do. If anyone knows how to do this I'd be grateful for some guidance. Thanks.